# Failed to load sound "sound\hurt3.wav", file probably missing from disk/repository

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
local AudioSource = nil

-- Define a table of sound file names (without the path)
local soundFiles = {
    "hurt1.wav",
    "hurt2.wav",
    "hurt3.wav",
    -- Add more sound files as needed
}

hook.Add("EntityTakeDamage", "UniqueNameForYourScript", function(target, dmginfo)
    -- Check if the target entity is a ragdoll
    if IsValid(target) and string.find(target:GetClass(), "ragdoll") then
        -- Choose a random sound file from the table
        local randomSoundName = table.Random(soundFiles)
        local soundPath = "sound/" .. randomSoundName
        
        sound.Play(soundPath, target:GetPos(), function(source, err, errname)
            if IsValid(source) then
                AudioSource = source
                source:Play()
            else
                print("Error playing sound: " .. errname)
            end
        end)
        print("OW!")
    else
        print("Not a ragdoll")
    end
end)
```

when i hit a ragdoll it says this in the console and i dont know what to do please help me

i was expecting to play a sound from the ragdoll

Comment: Your previous question uses `"hurt1.mp3"` rather than `"hurt1.wav"`, are the files mp3 files by chance?